# Do I need to upgrade GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

My daughter is trying to create a scene using kitbash 3D objects for a school coursework piece. Simpler things have worked fine, but this more complex scene crashes blender every time she goes to rendered viewport shading view. It gets stuck at 'compiling shaders' and a little while later Blender closes.

Processor: 6 core i5 9600k
Ram: 16GB
GPU: Geoforce GTX 1650

We've spent hours trying different settings. Strange this is my much less powerful laptop (8Gb and no GPU) managed to render it (though admittedly incredibly slowly).

The question is - I'm thinking of upgrading her GPU to a Geoforce RTX 2080 Ti. Before I spend the money I'm hoping for a bit of advice from people more knowledgeable than me.

Will this upgrade of GPU fix the problem?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kt7KnhjQpX12ojGQz6_IR18_RM57fh5_/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Could you please show us a .blend file of a  'more complex scene'?

Comment: Before wasting money make sure that is really the problem. Upgrade drivers, check debug logs to ensure that what is actually causing issues, GTX1650 is not the latest graphics card but is still relatively capable.

Comment: Hi :). Just a guess, but perhaps it just doesn't fit into the GPU's 4GB memory? You can still render it with CPU, which uses RAM to store render data.

Comment: Sorry - should have clarified. 'More complex' than her initial animations that worked fine. All very simple compared to what most will be creating. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kt7KnhjQpX12ojGQz6_IR18_RM57fh5_/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thanks all. Jachym - I know that you can force the render output to only use CPU, but I can't see  where to prevent the GPU being used when selecting rendered viewport shading.

Comment: And thanks Duarte. We have updated everything but I haven't checked crash logs - I'll have a rummage around and try to find where they are going.